# JQuery Timed FadeIn and FadeOut running for the first item only

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval, fadein

OK, guys I am trying to have sets of content (6) fade in and fade out continuously over time. The content is found in section tags which I have stripped of IDs because I have seen in some that this may cause problems. The section and it's content and the progress bar looks like this:

```
<progress id="Main-Progress" max="100"></progress>

<section class="class">
    <header>
    <p>stuff</p>
    </header>
    <table>
    </table>
</section>
```

The JS code is below, which is pretty simple, but does not work right. I have tried 2 different approaches as you will see below (for loop and JQuery.each). Both run through the 6 sections, but only the first one plays the transition code and then it stops. The for loop version gives me an error at the end too:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined 
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3

I have tried out both setTimeout and setInterval to run the function continuously and neither work.

```
function main ()
{
    var arrSections  = $('section');                        // get sections which contain judge/court room schedules
    var numSections  = arrSections.length;                  // get number of sections
    var incrProgress = Math.round( (1/numSections)*100 );   // get percentage increment for progress bar

    window.setTimeout ( cycleSlideshow(arrSections, numSections, incrProgress), 5 );
} // end function main

function cycleSlideshow (inSections, inNumSections, inIncrement)
{
    var ctr = 0;

    // Method 1 - JQuery.each
    // begin slideshow code using JQuery
    inSections.each( function ()
    {
    ctr++;
    $('#Main-Progress').attr('value', ctr * inIncrement);
    $(this).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);         
    }
    );

    // Method 2 - for loop
    // begin slideshow code using for loop
    for (ctr = 1; ctr <= inSections.length; ctr++)
    {
    // increment progress bar       
    $('#Main-Progress').attr('value', ctr * inIncrement);

    // slideshow effects
    $(this).fadeIn (1000);
    $(this).delay  (3000);
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    } // end for loop

} // end cycle slideshow
```

Comment: Add the relevant HTML  code please.

Comment: I had it in there but it was not showing.
I added more code just in case.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it is processing them all at once and not one at a time. =O

Comment: Today we are learning how JS is asynchronous. In all seriousness though, you'll want to set your counter outside the `setTimeout` and iterate from there.

Comment: er... `setInterval`. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Acting on information in your comment where you said it's running them all at once (rather than the assumption it was only the first one running), here is a simple way of forcing the loop to wait.

```
var ctr = 1
var loop = setInterval(function(){
  //do things here
  ctr++;
  if (ctr > inSections.length) ctr = 1;
}, (1 + 3 + 1) * 1000);
```

(note: I'm unsure if the `inSections.length` is correct, you should be able to figure out what I'm getting at though.)

So with this, you run through the loop and trigger all the commands. Then, you wait for the number of seconds that it take the commands to run (1 to fade in, 3 to display, 1 to fade out), and run through it all again.

Once the counter says "hey, we have reached the end" it resets to `1` (taking full advantage of JS and its tendency to play fast and loose with global scoped variables).

Comment: OK, I wasn't able to get that to work either.
I also tried code based on the W3C's slide show and I could not get that to work for my uses.

Comment: Would someone be willing to write the code for me if I send it to you?

There is not much to it. 
This code is all that is standing between me and finishing this little project.

Comment: OK, so now I am looking at JQuery Cycle2 plugin.
Any thoughts on that?

var ctr = 0;

$("#Court-Schedules").cycle({
    before  : setProgressBar(ctr, numSections),
    fx  : 'fade',
    speed : intFadeSec,
    timeout : intDelaySec,
    slides : '> section',
});

This is what I have currently. Running, but no progress bar update... so close!

Comment: OK, how do I get current slide index?

$("#Court-Schedules").cycle({
          before  : $('#Main-Progress').attr('value', $(this).data("cycle.opts").currSlide * incrProgress),
          fx  : 'fade',
          speed : intFadeSec,
          timeout : intDelaySec,
          slides : '> section',
         });

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question as I’m not in a position to provide any assistance right now and no one else is likely to see this.

Comment: Will do.Thanks for your help!
I really do appreciate your time.